# creating a dataset function using scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

so I am pretty new at Python, and I am trying to load a dataset from my computer using scikit. This is what my code looks like:

```
**whatever.py**

import numpy as np
import csv
from sklearn.datasets.base import Bunch

class Cortex_nuc:
    def cortex_nuclear():
        with open('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Data_Cortex_Nuclear4.csv') as csv_file:
            data_file = csv.reader(csv_file)
            temp = next(data_file)
            n_samples = int(float(temp[0]))
            n_features = int(float(temp[1]))
            data = np.empty((n_samples, n_features))
            target = np.empty((n_samples,), dtype=np.float64)

            for i, sample in enumerate(data_file):
                data[i] = np.asarray(sample[:-1], dtype=np.float64)
                target[i] = np.asarray(sample[-1], dtype=np.float64)

        return Bunch(data=data, target=target)
```

so then I import it into my project:

```
from whatever import Cortex_nuc
```

and after that I try to save it into df:

```
df = Cortex_nuc.cortex_nuclear()
```

Btw, this is what the dataset looks like:

[image: ...]

this is just a part of the dataset, otherwise it has 77 columns and about a thousand rows.

But I get an error message and I can't seem to figure out why it's happening. Here's the error message:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-a4935f2c187f> in <module>
----> 1 df = Cortex_nuc.cortex_nuclear()

~\whatever.py in cortex_nuclear()
     20 
     21             for i, sample in enumerate(data_file):
---> 22                 data[i] = np.asarray(sample[:-1], dtype=np.float64)
     23                 target[i] = np.asarray(sample[-1], dtype=np.float64)
     24 

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Can someone please help me? Thanks!

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables. Probably `(n_samples, n_features)` has values `(0,0)` and it creates array without places for data. You should rather create normal list and use `append()` inside `for`-loop. And after loop convert this list to array. Shorter: first learn to use `print()` to debug code. OR learn how to use real debuger.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a "*sklearn-like*" dataset in a `Bunch` object, you probably want something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils import Bunch

# For reproducing
from io import StringIO
csv_file = StringIO("""
target,A,B
0,0,0
1,0,1
1,1,0
0,1,1
""")

def load_xor(*, return_X_y=False):
    """Describe your data here."""
    _data_file = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    _data = Bunch()

    _data["DESCR"] = load_xor.__doc__
    _data["data"] = _data_file[["A", "B"]].to_numpy(dtype=np.float64)
    _data["target"] = _data_file["target"].to_numpy(dtype=np.float64)
    _data["target_names"] = np.array(["false", "true"])
    _data["feature_names"] = np.array(list(_data_file.drop(["target"], axis=1)))

    if return_X_y:
        return _data.data, _data.target
    return _data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Return and unpack the `X`, `y` tuple
    X, y = load_xor(return_X_y=True)
    print(X, y)
```

This is because `sklearn.datasets` typically return Bunch objects with specific attributes/keys (for explanations, see the "*Return*" section of the [`load_iris`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_iris.html#sklearn.datasets.load_iris) documentation):

```py
>>> from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
>>> data = load_iris()
>>> dir(data)
['DESCR', 'data', 'feature_names', 'filename', 'frame', 'target', 'target_names']
```